# Disable the popup menu of listview when no row is selected in delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a popup menu in my listview which i would like as disabled when the click is not on any row, I would like to know on what event of ListView or PopupMenu should i do this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Handle the `OnPopup` event of the popup menu like this:

```
procedure TForm1.PopupMenu1Popup(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ListView1.SelCount=0 then begin
    Abort;
  end;
end;
```

Don't try and use the mouse cursor in your logic because the popup menu may be invoked from the keyboard.

---

It turns out that you want to disable certain items on the menu dependent on the selection.  You should use actions for this and then you can centralise control of UI properties.  An action can be linked to a button, a popup menu item, a main menu item and so on.  You don't want to write code that enables and disables all of these separately—actions solve this problem.

Use the `OnUpdate` event for this.

```
procedure TForm1.Action1Update(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Action1.Enabled := ListView1.SelCount>0;
end;
```

Or sometimes you want the same `OnUpdate` for many actions which you would code list this:

```
procedure TForm1.FileActionsUpdate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  (Sender as TAction).Enabled := ListView1.SelCount>0;
end;
```

Comment: What u suggest will not show the popup when i click on the listview, however i want to show the menu but with disabled menus.Suggest please

Comment: `for i:=0 to PopupMenu1.Items.Count-1 do PopupMenu1.Items[i].Enabled := (ListView.SelCount > 0);`

Comment: @CyprUS Read your question again and see if you can see why I came to this conclusion.

Comment: @Cosmin I would not recommend that approach. Actions are the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Easy short anwser, to enable or disable one menu item by its name:

```
YourPopup.EntryNameYouWantToDisable.Enable:=(YourBooleanCondition);
```

Each TMenuItem has an `.Enable` property you can set to True or False.

Easy short anwser, to enable or disable one menu item by its position index:

```
YourPopup.Items[TheIndex].Enable:=(YourBooleanCondition);
```

You can go though all men items with a loop using: `.Items[TheIndex]` and know how much are with `.Items.Count`.

P.D.: They also have the `.Visible` so you can hide/show which ones you want.